# How to compute homotopy groups of torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The results are listed here: http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Homotopy_of_torus

Is there an intuitive way to understand these results?

In particular, why would the higher homotopy group be the trivial group?

Comment: Homotopy groups of a product of two spaces are the direct products of the respective homotopy groups of the factors. Torus is a product of two circles. If you know the homotopy groups of a circle you know those of a torus.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that n-torus is the product of n circles. I thought it was the product of n-spheres.

Comment: In addition, recall that the higher homotopy groups of a space $X$ that admits a universal cover are the same as the higher homotopy groups of $X$ itself. The universal cover of the $n$-torus is $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: To make @MikeMiller's comment slightly more precise; the induced homomorphisms $\pi_k(p)\colon \pi_k(Y)\to\pi_k(X)$ of a covering map $p\colon Y\to X$ is injective for $k=1$ and are isomorphisms for $k\geq 2$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\mathbb{T}^n$ denote the $n$-torus. This is the product of $n$ circles, i.e., $\mathbb{T}^n=(S^1)^n$. Thus, $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^n)=\prod^{n}\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}^n$. Since $\mathbb{T}^n$ admits a universal cover $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{T}^n$, for $i\geq 2$, the homomorphisms $\pi_i(\alpha):\pi_i(\mathbb{R}^n)\to\pi_i(\mathbb{T}^n)$ are isomorphisms. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homotopy equivalent to the point, $\pi_i(\mathbb{T}^n)$ is the trivial group for $i\geq 2$.